# Accessing Twilio TranscriptionText in a simple PHP application

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-twiml

I need to retrieve the transcription of a recording done with the Record Twiml verb but I can't get it to work.

Here's what I've tried:

**1. call.php**

```
<Response>    
  <Record maxLength="5" transcribe="true" action="getTranscription.php" />
</Response>
```

**2. getTranscription.php**

```
<Response>
  <Say>Here's your audio recording transcription: <?php echo $_REQUEST['TranscriptionText']; ?></Say>
</Response>
```

I have no problem recording voice and playing it back with the following code:

**1. call.php**

```
<Response>    
  <Record action="getRecording.php" />
</Response>
```

**2. getRecording.php**

```
<Response>
  <Say language="fr-CA">Here's your audio recording.</Say>
  <Play><?php echo $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']; ?></Play>
</Response>
```

It would be really appreciated if you guys could give me some hints on how to get the transcription back. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The transcription of a recording is done asynchronously to the call so you won't get the result when you get the webhook to the `action` URL.

So, you need to provide a [`transcribeCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe-callback) too.

```
<Response>    
  <Record maxLength="5" transcribe="true" action="getRecordResult.php" transcribeCallback="getTranscription.php" />
</Response>
```

There is no guarantee on how long the transcription will take, so it's hard to play the transcription back to the caller. It's better to use the `transcribeCallback` URL to save the transcription alongside the call record.

If you are trying to drive the call based on transcribing the caller's words then using `<Record>` and transcriptions is not recommended. Instead, I recommend you check out using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) with [`input="speech"`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#input). This will give you live voice transcription in the call.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Hope the rest of your application goes well.